# propagate MultiPointTouchArea event

Tags: events, touch, qml

It seems like there is no easy way to do this

For example :

```
Window {
    id: window
    width: 480
    height: 640

    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: console.debug("MouseArea Clicked !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!")
        preventStealing: true
    }

    TwoFingerArea {
        anchors.fill: parent

        enabled: true
        dragEnabled: true

        onZoomIn: console.debug("ZoomIn")
        onZoomOut:  console.debug("ZoomOut")
        onDragLeft: console.debug("DragLeft")
        onDragRight: console.debug("DragRight")
        onDragUp: console.debug("DragUp")
        onDragDown: console.debug("DragDown")
    }
}
```

TwoFingerArea :

```
MultiPointTouchArea {
    id: touch
    minimumTouchPoints: 2
    maximumTouchPoints: 2

    property var startPoint
    property var startScale
    property bool gestureDone: false
    property bool dragEnabled: true
    property int threshold: width / 12

    function dist(point1, point2) { return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(point1.x - point2.x, 2) + Math.pow(point1.y - point2.y, 2)) }
    function centerOf(point1, point2) { return Qt.point((point1.x + point2.x) / 2, (point1.y + point2.y) / 2) }

    signal zoomIn
    signal zoomOut
    signal dragLeft
    signal dragRight
    signal dragUp
    signal dragDown

    onPressed: {
        if (touchPoints.length === 2) {
            startPoint = centerOf(touchPoints[0], touchPoints[1])
            startScale = dist(touchPoints[0], touchPoints[1])
            gestureDone = false
        }
    }

    onTouchUpdated: {
        console.debug(touchPoints.length)
        if (touchPoints.length === 2 && !gestureDone) {
            var center = centerOf(touchPoints[0], touchPoints[1])
            var distance = dist(center, startPoint)
            var scale = dist(touchPoints[0], touchPoints[1])

            if      (scale - startScale > threshold) { zoomIn(); gestureDone = true }
            else if (scale - startScale < -threshold) { zoomOut(); gestureDone = true }
            else if (dragEnabled && distance > threshold) {
                var distX = startPoint.x - center.x
                var distY = startPoint.y - center.y
                var xBigger = Math.abs(distX) >= Math.abs(distY)
                if      (xBigger && distX >= 0) { dragLeft(); gestureDone = true }
                else if (xBigger && distX < 0)  { dragRight(); gestureDone = true }
                else if (distY >= 0)            { dragUp(); gestureDone = true }
                else                            { dragDown(); gestureDone = true }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Even though I told MultiPointTouchArea to only care about 2 points events, it will still capture 1 point event, and prevent the mouseArea from receiving the signal.

In the end, you can't have a touch gesture on top of a MouseArea of a Flickable or any mouse event item because they'll never receive any signal

Do you have any idea how to get around the problem ?

Comment: Did you give a try to the other events? I use `MultiPointTouchArea` inside a `Flickable` and it works fine for me but I've ended up implementing almost all the events. Also my logic is somewhat different from yours. I cannot look at it right now but I'll check it ASAP.

Comment: Yes, inside the flickable should be fine, with gestureStarted, but how about side by side with the flickable (and on top of it) ?

Comment: I guess you gave a try and it didn't work? :) I can't tell since I've used it a while ago.

Answer (score 0):

This is apparently a bug, I reported it there :

https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-49992